# Wordpress advanced taxonomy(category) filtering in post-types

Tags: wordpress, rest, search

I'm using Wordpress as an headless CMS/REST. For a post I got different kind of categories, these are divided by three main categories, each having other categories linked to one of these three parents. With the [standard filtering options](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#retrieve-a-post) I found on the website.

What's possible now is to query a post and enter the category id of either of these sub-categories and it will retrieve all posts linked to them. What I'm trying to find is a way to query first posts that both have these sub-categories, instead of just all the posts that either have one of those. Second, (if it's possible) it can only query one sub-category of each the parent-category.

Hope it's a bit clear. What's possible now is that I can query all the posts linked to one categories, but I can't exclude them if they don't have the same one (and if it's possible, exclude choosing more then one sub-category of one main category).

If anyone has an idea how to do this by making a custom function or with a plugin, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Hi there Beef stew. The `WP_Query` `tax_query` parameter can make use of `AND / OR` operators but it has its limitations. You could off course write custom `SQL` queries where you can query for anything you like if you're comfortable with plain SQL.

Comment: @jrswgtr I'm going to look into it, thanks! Plain SQL isn't a problem if we can make it work with a custom function.